# Setting up a plain graphene nested query

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have successfully created an all graphene query that responds to

```
query {
    person (id: "Mary") {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

I now want to extend this to be able to loop through all people and return similar data for each.

```
query {
    people {
        count
        allPersons {
           name
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the `resolve_allPersons` resolver in `people` to call the `person` resolver for each person?

Answer (score 8):

Second query you've described can be done with custom type, for example:

```
class AllPeopleType(graphene.ObjectType):
    count = graphene.Int()
    all_persons = graphene.List(YourPersonType)

    def resolve_count(self, info, **kwargs):
        # assumed that django used on backend
        return Person.objects.count()

    def resolve_all_persons(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Person.objects.all()
```

and query:

```
class YourQuery(object):
    # person = ...
    people = graphene.Field(AllPeopleType)

    def resolve_people(self, info):
        return AllPeopleType()
```