# Accessing the data of the parent graphene.ObjectType from the nested class

Tags: python, nested, graphql, graphene-python, resolver

As mentioned
[in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748236/setting-up-a-plain-graphene-nested-query), a nested query in graphene in python can be done. Is there a way to access the data of a parent query?

With reference to the same question

```
query {
    person (id: "Mary") {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

The nested query:

```
query {
    people {
        group
        allPersons {
           name
        }
    }
}
```

How would I access `group` from `people` in the resolver for `allPersons`.

Answer (score 1):

The graphene documentation doesn't make this clear.

As the [page mentioned in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748236/setting-up-a-plain-graphene-nested-query) the root query is as follows:

```
class YourQuery(object):
    # person = ...
    people = graphene.Field(AllPeopleType)

    def resolve_people(self, info):
        return AllPeopleType()
```

To access the variables of the parent of `Person` which triggered `resolve_all_persons`, i.e `AllPersons`

```
class AllPeopleType(graphene.ObjectType):
    group = graphene.Int()
    all_persons = graphene.List(Person)

    def resolve_all_persons(self, info, **kwargs):
        # This allows us to access group of AllPersons
        personGroup = self['group']
        return Person.objects.all()
```

However this **will not work** if `all_persons` resolver is defined as

```
all_persons = graphene.List(Person, resolver = yourResolverFunctionHere)
```

This is becuase the resolver for `Person` (and anything within `AllPersons`) must be a member of the Parent class `AllPersons` which resolves its own variables.